# Problem With [Header("header")] in unity C# before {get; private set;}

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

code is as follows:

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {
    [Header("Physics")]
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpSpeed;
    private bool stillOnce;

    [Header("Components")]
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    
    
    [Header("Game")]
    public Vector3 respawnPoint { get; private set; }
    
    private LevelManager levelManager;
```

It throws the error

> Attribute Header is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on field declarations

Not sure how `{ get; private set; }` works or what that error means.
First time asking a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: The error says that you can not apply this attribute on properties. They can be used only on fields. You can declare a field and use this header on it and create a property wrapping this field. `[Header("Game")]
    private Vector3 respawnPoint; public Vector3 RespawnPoint {get { return respawnPoint;}}`

Comment: You now assign value to respawnPoint from inside the class and access it's value from outside of class using property

Answer (score 3):

```
public Vector3 respawnPoint { get; private set; }
```

is a [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) not a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)! To be exact it's an [auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#auto-implemented-properties).

Unity doesn't serialize properties by default (see [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)) and therefore having a Inspector drawer attribute on it doesn't even make sense ;)

---

You can either have a [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields) and rather serialize that one like

```
[Header("Game")]
// forces a private field to get serialized
[SerializeField]
// private backing field for the property 
private Vector3 _respawnPoint;

// public readonly access
public Vector3 respawnPoint => _respawnPoint;
```

using [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) to force the private field to be serialized anyway (by default only public ones would be serialized). And then of course assign the private field everywhere you would have assigned the property.

---

Or you can give it a shot and force Unity to serialize the property using (not sure if this will work for the header attribute though - currently only on the phone)

```
[Header("Game")]
[field: SerializeField]
public Vector3 respawnPoint { get; private set; }
```

this is unfortunately not documented but treats the property like a field for the serialization (with limits: the getter and setter are not called when the value is changed via the Inspector - which again doesn't really matter with auto-properties)

Answer (score 2):

To add onto what [@derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) said because they were almost there; the `field:` part of an attribute is used to target the backing field of an auto-implemented property. So to make a `[Header]` attribute work with auto-implemented properties you just need to write it as:

```cs
[field: Header("YourHeader")]
[field: SerializeField]
public Vector3 respawnPoint { get; private set; }
```

Note: A header will not appear if the field its targeting is not serialized, therefore you must also include the `[field: SerializeField]` attribute if you want this to work.